# Hide plot and command window for executable

Tags: matlab, plot, command, executable, matlab-figure

I am looking for the golden command, with which I can create an executable which will not show any images or command window when it is started. My executable creates and saves some plots frequently and I don't want it to pop up all the time. I tried -R nodisplay etc, but none of these worked. Any idea what can I do to hide these two?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: if you are looking to hide the command window for a Matlab compiled executable, look at the compiler switch `-e` (although it only works in Windows system I think)

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
h=figure();
set(h, 'Visible', 'off');
plot(rand(100));
% save with such as
saveas(h,'myplot.png');
```

work?

This definitely works in MATLAB, I assume it would do in a MATLAB executable.

Alternatively (but unsure on how the preferences are sent to executable), you can set the default option for visibility with:

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'off');
```

This will not show any figure unless specified. However, again, not sure how this preferences are translated to an executable if you use `deploytool` or the  MATLAB compiler